# lldb stop at breakpoint at a certain value of a variable

Tags: c, debugging, variables, lldb

How can I make `lldb` stop if a variable has a certain value? Something like: `br set --file fnc.c --line 10 if I==5`, where line 10 just contains a `printf` statement that doesn't involve `I` and the value of `I` is set before line 10. I tried the preceding command, but it still stops at line 10, regardless of the value of `I`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the `lldb` docs, the syntax is

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --name foo --condition '(int)strcmp(y,"hello") == 0'
(lldb) br s -n foo -c '(int)strcmp(y,"hello") == 0'
```

For more details see https://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: What should I write to `--name`? Executable name?

Comment: The name of the function. For a specific line, use ```--line```. See https://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html for more details